# ng-grid | ui-grid disable grid menu

Tags: ng-grid

[Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/t1ItGsks8YCMKc8sr43m)

`enableGridMenu: false` does not seem to disable the grid menu for ui-grid. Is there a way in the options to disable it or do I need to hack it by hiding it via CSS?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the option is `enableColumnMenus: false`